# Spring cloud config server - more than 1 properties file per app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

Does anybody knows if it is possible to expose more than 1 property file per application in Spring Cloud config server?

For example I would like to have defined in my git repo properties for the same app, but in different files:

- myapp-customer-services.yml
- myapp-products-services.yml

and have all those properties defined inside the files, exposed under "myapp".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not possible currently. I'm not sure it really makes much sense to be honest, since you can easily clearly delineate different sets of properties within a YAML file using separate documents.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to expose more than 1 property file per application in Spring Cloud config server

You can access it in you client by using following properties

first specify profile which you want

example

```
myapp-customer.yml
myapp-products.yml
spring.profiles.active=customer,products
spring.cloud.config.name=myapp
```